# VTK polydata not updating after CellDataToPointData filter

Tags: python, vtk

I am trying to convert a `vtkPolyData` object that contains some point data and some cell data, into all point data. The `vtkPolyData` object starts off from an STL file, then I calculate the Gaussian Curvature (point data) and Scalar Gradient (cell data).

I am using the `vtkCellDataToPointData` filter/function to then convert all the data to point data.

My code currently looks like this:

```
import vtk

#get the gradient
ocurv = vtk.vtkCurvatures()
ocurv.SetInputData(odata)
ocurv.SetCurvatureTypeToGaussian()
ocurv.Update()
ocurv = ocurv.GetOutput()
ocurv.GetPointData().SetActiveScalars('Gauss_Curvature')
ocurvdiff = vtk.vtkCellDerivatives()
ocurvdiff.SetInputData(ocurv)
ocurvdiff.SetVectorModeToComputeGradient()
ocurvdiff.Update()
ocurvdiff = ocurvdiff.GetOutput()

#convert cell data to point data
grad = vtk.vtkCellDataToPointData()
grad.ProcessAllArraysOn()
grad.SetInputData(ocurvdiff)
grad.Update()
grad = grad.GetOutput()

#get the point centered gradient
grad_data = vtk_to_numpy(grad.GetPointData().GetArray(2))
```

here `odata` is a `vtkPolyData` object instantiated by reading a STL file.

The problem is that `grad_data` comes out empty:

```
>>> grad.GetPointData().GetArrayName(2) 
'ScalarGradient'
>>> vtk_to_numpy(grad.GetPointData().GetArray(2))
array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=float64)
```

When I write out `ocurvdiff` to a VTP file, it has the vector called `ScalarGradient`, with Mag/x/y/z components as cell data. But, when I write out `grad` to a VTP file after doing the cell to point filter, this data is not there anymore.

Is there some kind of update that I am missing? Why is my cell data that is being converted to point data coming out empty? FYI it's a vector not a scalar.

Image below of `ocurvdiff` after being written to VTP with `ScalarGradient` cell data:

[image]

Comment: I see you use ParaView. Do you have same problem by using the `CellDataToPointData` in ParaView ?

Comment: no , just need to have a coded solution - and really paraview uses the vtk.vtkCellDataToPointData() filter anyways, I'm sure it would work in paraview, but wondering what I'm missing in my code

Comment: I tried your code using a polydata representing a triangulated surface, the array 'ScalarGradient' looks perfectly fine. Could there be something wrong with your input data?